# Using JavaScript, how to change Header to an H3 if it nested inside an H2?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, javascript-objects, jquery-events

I have this component called `topComponent` that has a `title`, `body`, and `link`. The `Title` is an H2.

```
<div class="topComponent"> 
        <div class="Wrapper">
            <h2 class="title">About The Eartht</h2>
            <div class="container htmlText">
             <p>Here is some information about the Earth..</p>
         </div>
            <div class="infoLink">
            <a href="........." target="_blank"</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

However, if this `title` header is nested inside another header that is an H2, then I am trying make this `title` header an h3. Basically let say there is an HTML like this:

```
    <h2 class="bigHeader">About The Earth Parent</h2> // Parent Header
    <div class="topComponent"> 
                <div class="Wrapper">
                    <h2 class="title">About The Eartht</h2>
                    <div class="container htmlText">
                     <p>Here is some information about the Earth..</p>
                 </div>
                    <div class="infoLink">
                    <a href="........." target="_blank"</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Here, there is a parent header called `bigHeader` that is an H2. So in this case, I want the `title` header to change to H3 instead of h2, since there is already a parent h2 on top.

**Question**: How can we determine if the title should be an h2 or h3 depending on if there was an H2 parent for this element through a script?

Here is the Javascript:

```
$(Wrapper).each(function(){
  var count = 0;
  $("h2").each(function(){
    if(count > 0)
    {
      $(this).replaceWith($('<h3>' + this.innerHTML + '</h3>'));
    }
    count++;
  });
});
```

The problem with the above code is that, it's changing the h2 headers **outside** of this component as well. I was hoping the changes will only happen within the `Wrapper` div. Not sure why it's not selecting the H2's only with in the wrapper.

Comment: Because you are selecting all h2s. You are not selecting the h2s in the wrapper. Not sure how your code is running since `$(Wrapper)` appears to be wrong unless `Wrapper` is a variable.

Comment: @epascarello I am trying to select the H2 that are in the `wrapper` div. That's why I used `$(Wrapper).each(function(){` . But it looks like it's selecting all the h2 in the page.

Comment: because `$("h2")` seelcts all the h2s on the page... it has no clue it is supposed to look in the wrapper

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution.

```js
var container = document.getElementById("container");
var h2 = container.getElementsByTagName("h2");

if(h2.length == 2){
  var h3 = document.createElement('h3');
  h3.innerText = h2.innerText
  h2[1].replaceWith(h3);
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <h2 class="bigHeader">About The Earth Parent</h2> // Parent Header
  <div class="topComponent">
    <div class="Wrapper">
      <h2 class="title">About The Eartht</h2>
      <div class="container htmlText">
        <p>Here is some information about the Earth..</p>
      </div>
      <div class="infoLink">
        <a href="........." target="_blank" </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried you example, but my h3 title is saying undefined, and I think in your example also the h3 title is undefined. Do you happen to know why?

Answer (score 0):

unclear how the HTML really plays into this. But if it follows the same pattern with a div as a sibling to the first h2, you can use a selector to find it. You can than use replaceWith

```js
$("h2 + div h2").replaceWith(function() {
  return $("<h3>", {
    class: this.className,
    html: $(this).html()
  });
});
```

```css
h2 { color: red; }
h3 { color: green; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2 class="bigHeader">About The Earth Parent</h2>
<div class="topComponent">
  <div class="Wrapper">
    <h2 class="title">About The Earth</h2>
    <div class="container htmlText">
      <p>Here is some information about the Earth..</p>
    </div>
    <div class="infoLink">
      <a href="#" target="_blank">X</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call the `h2` inside of the Wrapper class.

With `$(Wrapper).each` you say, enter in that function per child, don't say change the child, and you are changing all h2 of page

```
$(Wrapper).each(function(){
  var count = 0;
  $(".Wrapper h2").each(function(){
    if(count > 0)
    {
      $(this).replaceWith($('<h3>' + this.innerHTML + '</h3>'));
    }
    count++;
  });
});
```